# Show that exists $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x)*P(y) < 0 \ ; x,y\in \Bbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I would like to ask how could I perform following proof:

> Prove(show) that exists such $x$ and $y$ that $P(x)*P(y) < 0$. Where $P(x)$ and $P(y)$ are polynomials.
>   $\forall\ x,y\in \Bbb C$

Comment: What if $P$ is always non-negative (for example $x\rightarrow x^2$)

Comment: This is false in general. For a particular polynomial, you would have to show that the polynomial is not always $\ge 0$, nor is it always $\le 0$.

Comment: but in general if x and y were complex numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

So, your edited question is that if for every polynomial $P$ there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $P(x)\cdot P(y)\in \mathbb{R}$ and furthermore $P(x)\cdot P(y)<0$.

One way to prove this is using the fundamental theorem of algebra. Apply this to the polynomials $P-1$ and $P+1$. Then according to the fundamental theorem, there exist complex numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x)-1=0$ and $P(y)+1=0$. Thus $P(x)\cdot P(y)=-1<0$. Of course similar arguments show that any value can be attained.

As noted in the comments, demanding $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ is too much, as the counterexample $P(x)=x^2$ by Amr shows.